# problems getting the value of a field in a Ext.data.Model

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I need to set values ​​in a text field, obtaining a data.Model these values​​, but when I run the function anywhere in the code, sends me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'get' of undefined

But if I run it from a button works fine.

this is the code:

```
function SetterValues() {

                var rec = store_usr.getAt(0);
        Ext.getCmp('name_usr').setValue(rec.get("user"));
        Ext.getCmp('nom_usr').setValue(rec.get("name"));
        Ext.getCmp('ape_usr').setValue(rec.get("LastName"));

}
```

Help please! because I can not run it from anywhere in my code!

Comment: what prints `console.log(store_usr.getCount())` if you put this before `store_usr.getAt(0)`

Comment: console.log(store_usr.getCount())   returns me 0

Comment: then your store is empty. so either you don't get data or your `SetterValues()` function is called before the stores `load` event is fired. if you enter `store_usr.getCount()` into the console after the site is fully loaded do you get a number greater 0 ?

Comment: Please don't put solved in your title. You mark the question as answered by accepting an answer, or if an existing answer doesn't solve your problem, you add your own answer, and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're receiving indicates that the `rec` variable is undefined. Are you sure that your `store_usr` exists, and is loaded? If so, does `store_usr.getAt(0)` return anything?

Comment: I'm sure if there is, because if I do: 

console.log(store_usr.getAt(0)) 

He shows [Object object] 

but this line is failing when I do .get(field)

Comment: Do you know what fields are available on that object? The error you've pasted indicates `rec` is undefined. If it was defined, but the `get` method didn't exist, you'd see `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.